# setTimeout First Delay does not take Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

setTimeout doesn't work as expected because it will execute the codes below subsequently without waiting for the delay to run the first argument of 'setTimeout'

```
(function() {
    var a = ['#bird','#flower','#cat'];
    var totalno = settings.imageArray.length;
    function rotateImages(start) {
        var nextImage = start + 1;
        if(nextImage % totalno == 0){
        nextImage=0;
        }

        //do animate here
        $(settings.imageArray).fadeOut();

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            rotateImages(++start % totalno);
        }, settings.imageArray[start].delay);
    }
    rotateImages(0);
})();
```

Is there a way to write it so that it doesnt fade out right away for the first image?

a simplified version would be :

```
(function() {
    var a = ['#bird','#flower','#cat'];

    function rotateImages(start) {
             //do something here

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            rotateImages(++start % a.length;);
        }, 1000);
    }
    rotateImages(0);
})();
```

Comment: What is settings.imageArray[start].delay set to when the code executes (checking in something like Firebug)

Comment: it depends on the object.. it's properties are the image name, image delay and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it will execute the codes below
>   subsequently without waiting for the
>   delay to run the first argument of
>   'setTimeout'

It looks like you're starting the first rotate directly.  Instead of:

```
rotateImages(0);
```

Try to start the first rotate with a delay, like:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
        rotateImages(0);
    }, settings.imageArray[0].delay);
```

Comment: so i have to create another timeout? the parameter passed to the rotateImage has to be variable base on the array

Comment: Aren't you just passing 0 to rotateImages?

Comment: Yup. thanks! I've actually created a separate function to call so the first time wont be activated!